# How to separate a file of words into a list in LiveCode

Tags: list, livecode

I'm *really* new to LiveCode and I have a file of words, each one on a new line. I want to write these into a list variable in LiveCode, so that I can choose one of them at random later. If I were to do this in python, it would look something like this:

```
    list1 = []
    with open('words.txt') as f:
        for line in f:
            list1.append(line.strip())
```

However, I am unsure of how to do this in LiveCode and have been unable to find anything telling me how. Help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can place the contents of an external text file into a variable like this:

```
put url ("file:words.txt") into list1
```

Use the word "file" to tell LiveCode that you want to access the external file as text, rather binary, in which case you'd use "binfile:".

Comment: would that file have to be in the same directory as the compiled file, or would I need to specify the directory for the file somehow?

Comment: You should specify the directory.  The specialFolderPath function allows you to automatically reference many of the common folder locations on different devices. The "resources" option is a good one.

Answer (score 0):

There is an easy way to do what you want. Assume that `myFile` contains the path to your file.

```
put url ("binfile:" & myFile) into myList
replace crlf with lf in myList
replace numToChar(13) with lf in myList
put any line of myList into myWord
```

The variable `myWord` now contains a random line (word) from your file.